# sshd_config match rule Host not working

Tags: openssh, sshd

Trying to add specific rules based on hostnames in sshd_config. `UseDNS` is set to `yes`

```
Match Host remote.address.com
    AuthenticationMethods "publickey"
```

When trying to connect from that host the rule not applied.
However when the IP address is given - it works

```
Match Address 192.168.0.10
    AuthenticationMethods "publickey"
```

What is missing to able separate rules by hostnames?